# How to get beginning to end of last week independent of today's date (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, intervals, snapshot

I am  trying to indicate all rows with last week's data (Monday-Sunday) using the following, gives me the data from (Tue-Mon) 2 feb-8 feb - so it is dynamic depending on the day of this week and tomorrow will give me the data from Wed-Tue. Any idea how to fix this:

```
case when `Date` >= date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and 
`Date`< (date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)+7) then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you could try using week()  checking for the same week of curdate()

```
case when week(`Date`) = weeek(curdate()) 
    AND year(`Date`) = year(curdate()) then 1 else 0 end
```

or for the previous week

```
case when week(`Date`) = weeek(curdate())-1 
  AND year(`Date`) = year(curdate()) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: But this one would identify the current week's data, not last weeks, no? And I am looking to indicate last week's data from Monday to Saturday.

Comment: what is the last week ?  . .. the actual week -1?? .. try explain better ..

Comment: My bad. If today is February 9th, last week's data in my case would be data between February 1st to February 7th. (Monday to Sunday)